# javascript css style display none by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles

I have the following code:

```
//new image on load
function theNewImg_onload(){ 
    $bgimg.data("newImageW",this.width).data("newImageH",this.height);
    BackgroundLoad($bgimg,this.width,this.height,this.src);
}
```

Everytime i change the image background on the website, the javascript is updating the CSS with the style="display:none" by default, is there a way to tell the JS to set up display:block?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
BackgroundLoad is:

```
function BackgroundLoad($this,imageWidth,imageHeight,imgSrc){
    $this.fadeOut("fast",function(){
        $this.attr("src", "").attr("src", imgSrc); //change image source
        FullScreenBackground($this,imageWidth,imageHeight); //scale background image
        $preloader.fadeOut("fast",function(){$this.fadeIn("slow");});
        var imageTitle=$img_title.data("imageTitle");
        if(imageTitle){
            $this.attr("alt", imageTitle).attr("title", imageTitle);
            $img_title.fadeOut("fast",function(){
                $img_title.html(imageTitle).fadeIn();
            });
        } else {
            $img_title.fadeOut("fast",function(){
                $img_title.html($this.attr("title")).fadeIn();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**WORKAROUND**:
I founded that I can override that default on the CSS marking it as !important:

```
#bgimg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: block !important;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Try a non-jquery code and see if it works.

Comment: What does `BackgroundLoad` look like?

Comment: You can "tell" the scripting engine to do something by **coding**.

Comment: Styles don't change by themselves. If it's happening, it's because something in your application is telling it to do so. Find that and fix it.

Comment: why do you use fadeOut if you don't want display none?